Integration of composite function
I am confused about the integration of a nested function / composite function. Let's say the function is defined as follows
\begin{equation}
I(x) = f(g(x))
\end{equation}
Obviously, when taking the derivative with respect to $x$ one obtains by means of the chain rule
\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\,x}\,f(g(x)) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\,g(x)}f(g(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}\,g(x)}{\mathrm{d}\,x} = f^{\prime}(g(x))g^{\prime}(x)
\end{equation}
But what does the following integral equal to
\begin{equation}
J = \int\,f^{\prime}( g(x)) \mathrm{d}\,x
\end{equation}
This probelm reminds me somehow of this question and this question. But maybe I am connecting wrong things here.
Thanks for helping out.

As stated in some of the answers in the questions you've linked, there's no general antiderivative for $f(g(x))$, and taking the derivative of the outside function doesn't really change it because we can just write $f'(u) = F(u)$ and we get $\int f'(g(x)) dx = \int F(g(x)) dx$, meaning that we haven't really gained anything.

thanks for the clarification
